# Error when doing the JavaFX FXML tutorial from Oracle

Tags: java, fxml

Good Day,
I a working my way through the official JavaFX FXML tutorial (See source code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/FXMLExample.zip)). However when I compile it using the Netbeans IDE I get the following error:

Can anyone help me with this

I'm running JDK 1.7 and JavaFX 2.0

> init: Deleting:
>   C:\Users\riash\Documents\Riaz\Personal\Java\Samples\FXMLExample\build\built-jar.properties
>   deps-jar: Updating property file:
>   C:\Users\riash\Documents\Riaz\Personal\Java\Samples\FXMLExample\build\built-jar.properties
>   compile: Detected JavaFX Ant API version 1.1 Launching  task
>   from C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0 SDK\tools\ant-javafx.jar
>   Signing JAR:
>   C:\Users\riash\Documents\Riaz\Personal\Java\Samples\FXMLExample\dist\FXMLExample.jar
>   to
>   C:\Users\riash\Documents\Riaz\Personal\Java\Samples\FXMLExample\dist\FXMLExample.jar
>   as nb-jfx
>
> Warning:  The signer certificate will expire within six months. Enter
>   Passphrase for keystore: Enter key password for nb-jfx:  Launching
>    task from C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle\JavaFX 2.0
>   SDK\tools\ant-javafx.jar Skip jar copy to itself: FXMLExample.jar
>   jfx-deployment: jar: run: Jun 19, 2012 9:10:33 PM
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader logException SEVERE: The following error
>   occurred at line 48 in file
>   /C:/Users/riash/Documents/Riaz/Personal/Java/Samples/FXMLExample/build/classes/fxmlexample/fxml_example.fxml[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@1bb3a11
>   Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
> at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     
> at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     
> at
>   com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:453)     
> at
>   com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:537) 
> Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method     
> at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown
>   Source)   
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown
>   Source)   
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown
>   Source)   
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) 
> Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException: javafx.scene.layout.GridPane does not have
>   a default property.

Comment: can you  check the versions of jdk and javafx and make sure both are compatible / compliant to each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading your JavaFX runtime to at least 2.1 will fix your problem.

The sample source you reference is designed for a 2.1 runtime, not a 2.0 runtime.

The reason the new source is incompatible with 2.0 is that 2.1 adds an inherited @DefaultProperty annotation to the Pane class (this annotated behaviour gets inherited by GridPane).  Because of this, when you write fxml using 2.1 you can omit certain tags which get defaulted, making the 2.1 fxml less verbose than what is required for 2.0.  A [full explanation](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/01/javafx-21-javafx-2s-defaultproperty.html) of this is provided by Dustin Marx in his blog.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from JavaFx 2.0 to JavaFx 2.2 will fix this problem.