# Java Runtime Exception. Java FX

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I have tried to learn Java FX so I used some of the Oracle Eample Code but when I tried to run it in Netbean IDE, It gives me a Runtime Error. Here is a Piece of code :

```
    public class WebViewTestOne {
    private  Scene scene;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Web View");
    scene = new Scene(new Browser(),750,500, Color.web("#666970"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");        
    stage.show();
     }

public static void main(String[] args){
      launch(args);

     }
                              }
```

and this is the Exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Error: class webviewtest.one.WebViewTestOne is not a subclass of javafx.application.Application
at javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:254)
at webviewtest.one.WebViewTestOne.main(WebViewTestOne.java:33)
Java Result: 1
```

So what is wrong? I mean since this is an Example from the official Site, why even there is an error? ( the error happens at the     launch(args)

**EDIT**: Ok based on the Answer by **rob** I added the Extension that I missed from the example, Now it gives even much more exception after I tried to extend the code. below is the new Code and the Log for the exception.

```
   package webviewtest.one;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
    import javafx.application.Platform;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change;
    import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.Event;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;
    import javafx.geometry.HPos;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.geometry.VPos;
    import javafx.scene.Node;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
    import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
    import javafx.scene.image.Image;
    import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;

    import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.scene.web.PopupFeatures;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebHistory.Entry;
    import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class WebViewTestOne extends Application{

    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // apply CSS style
        scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css");
        // show stage
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
class Browser extends Region {

    private HBox toolBar;
    private static String[] imageFiles = new String[]{
        "product.png",
        "blog.png",
        "documentation.png",
        "partners.png",
        "help.png"
    };
    private static String[] captions = new String[]{
        "Products",
        "Blogs",
        "Documentation",
        "Partners",
        "Help"
    };
    private static String[] urls = new String[]{
        "http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html",
        "http://blogs.oracle.com/",
        "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/index.html",
        "http://www.oracle.com/partners/index.html",
      //  WebViewSample.class.getResource("help.html").toExternalForm()
    };
    final ImageView selectedImage = new ImageView();
    final Hyperlink[] hpls = new Hyperlink[captions.length];
    final Image[] images = new Image[imageFiles.length];
    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    final Button showPrevDoc = new Button("Toggle Previous Docs");
    final WebView smallView = new WebView();
    final ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    private boolean needDocumentationButton = false;

    public Browser() {
        //apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");

        for (int i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
            // create hyperlinks
            Hyperlink hpl = hpls[i] = new Hyperlink(captions[i]);
            Image image = images[i] =
            new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageFiles[i]));
            hpl.setGraphic(new ImageView(image));
            final String url = urls[i];
            final boolean addButton = (hpl.getText().equals("Documentation"));

            // process event 
            hpl.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                    needDocumentationButton = addButton;
                    webEngine.load(url);
                }
            });
        }

        comboBox.setPrefWidth(60);

        // create the toolbar
        toolBar = new HBox();
        toolBar.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        toolBar.getStyleClass().add("browser-toolbar");
        toolBar.getChildren().add(comboBox);
        toolBar.getChildren().addAll(hpls);
        toolBar.getChildren().add(createSpacer());

        //set action for the button
        showPrevDoc.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Event t) {
                webEngine.executeScript("toggleDisplay('PrevRel')");
            }           
        });

        smallView.setPrefSize(120, 80);

        //handle popup windows
        webEngine.setCreatePopupHandler((PopupFeatures config) -> {
            smallView.setFontScale(0.8);
            if (!toolBar.getChildren().contains(smallView)) {
                toolBar.getChildren().add(smallView);
            }
            return smallView.getEngine();
        });

        //process history
        final WebHistory history = webEngine.getHistory();
        history.getEntries().addListener((Change<? extends Entry> c) -> {
            c.next();
            c.getRemoved().stream().forEach((e) -> {
                comboBox.getItems().remove(e.getUrl());
            });
            c.getAddedSubList().stream().forEach((e) -> {
                comboBox.getItems().add(e.getUrl());
            });
        });

        //set the behavior for the history combobox               
        comboBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent ev) {
                int offset =
                        comboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()
                        - history.getCurrentIndex();
                history.go(offset);
            }
        });


        // process page loading
        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<State>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> ov,
                    State oldState, State newState) {
                    toolBar.getChildren().remove(showPrevDoc);    
                    if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                            JSObject win = 
                                (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                            win.setMember("app", new JavaApp());
                            if (needDocumentationButton) {
                                toolBar.getChildren().add(showPrevDoc);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        );

        // load the home page        
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com/products/index.html");

        //add components
        getChildren().add(toolBar);
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

    // JavaScript interface object
    public class JavaApp {

        public void exit() {
            Platform.exit();
        }
    }

    private Node createSpacer() {
        Region spacer = new Region();
        HBox.setHgrow(spacer, Priority.ALWAYS);
        return spacer;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        double tbHeight = toolBar.prefHeight(w);
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h-tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
        layoutInArea(toolBar,0,h-tbHeight,w,tbHeight,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefWidth(double height) {
        return 750;
    }

    @Override
    protected double computePrefHeight(double width) {
        return 600;
    }
}
```

and this is the Exception Log:

```
    Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:363)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:303)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)    
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$48/128893786.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1099)
at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:684)
at webviewtest.one.Browser.<init>(WebViewTestOne.java:104)
at webviewtest.one.WebViewTestOne.start(WebViewTestOne.java:49)
at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)    
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/1135703189.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$45/1051754451.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/135339377.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/1775282465.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1109371569.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
Exception running application webviewtest.one.WebViewTestOne
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend Application. I believe that is what the error means.

Here is an example from Java FX Site:

```
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.scene.Group;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

 public class MyApp extends Application 
 {
     public void start(Stage stage) 
     {
        Circle circ = new Circle(40, 40, 30);
        Group root = new Group(circ);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);

        stage.setTitle("My JavaFX Application");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Extend application and try it. Make sure you copied everything right because example 5 of the same code extends application.

Comment: please take look at the Edit

Comment: Do you have the css file? Because it looks like is being thrown from inside the add method. It says it was Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null

Comment: where did u get the idea for the CSS ? from the code I can not see any relation between it with CSS . and the tutorial did not say anything about the CSS either.

Comment: This line form your code above: scene.getStylesheets().add("webviewsample/BrowserToolbar.css"); you are suppose to have a folder webviewsample with BrowserToolbar.css if you don't have it when it tries to open it, it throws an exception. If you just copy paste the code to IDE you are missing this file. try to locate complete project.

Comment: Check the version you are running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111645/error-when-doing-the-javafx-fxml-tutorial-from-oracle